# Jquery add class in a class function using "this" as reference

Tags: jquery, function, class, this

I'm trying to use a class as reference to addClass removeClass with jquery (this). I need a universal reference like class as I'm adding dynamic elements to the page and need all those elements to use the function.

When I reference an element by ID everything works great. When I reference the element by class I can't seem to modify the class or the input's value.

**HTML**

```
<input id="part"  size="15" type="text" class="part" name="part" value=""/>
```

**Jquery (Response Okay; AddClass, RemoveClass, this.val(data), not okay)**

```
$(document).on('blur', '.part', function(){
    var oldNumber = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
    $.post("part-interchange.php",{ part:$(this).val() } ,function(data) {
    //no data back then add class Red remove Green
        if (data=='no') {
                $(this).removeClass('shadeChange');
                $(this).removeClass('shadeGood');
                $(this).addClass('shadeBad');
        } else if (data=='yes') {
        $(this).removeClass('shadeChange');
                $(this).removeClass('shadeBad');
                $(this).addClass('shadeGood');
         } else if (data!='yes') {
                $(this).removeClass('shadeBad');
                $(this).removeClass('shadeGood');
                $(this).addClass('shadeChange');
                $(this).val(data);
           }
     });
});
```

However if I reference using the html ID the Jquery Works great

**Working Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#part").blur(function() {
            var oldNumber = $("#part").val().toUpperCase();
            $.post("part-interchange.php",{ part:$("#part").val() } ,function(data) {
                //no data back then add class Red remove Green
                if (data=='no') {
                    $("#part").removeClass('shadeChange');
                    $("#part").removeClass('shadeGood');
                    $("#part").addClass('shadeBad');
                    }
                // else if is part then add green remove red
                 else if (data=='yes') {
                    $("#part").removeClass('shadeChange');
                    $("#part").removeClass('shadeBad');
                    $("#part").addClass('shadeGood');
                 }
                 else if(data!='yes') {
                     $("#part").removeClass('shadeBad');
                     $("#part").removeClass('shadeGood');
                     $("#part").addClass('shadeChange');
                     $("#part").val(data);
                 }
                     });
                });
        });
```

**CSS**

```
.shadeGood{background-color:#D9F2E6;font-weight:700;color:#390}
.shadeBad{background-color:#F7E6E9;font-weight:700;color:red}
.shadeChange{background-color:#c7d9fc;font-weight:700;color:#0028f0}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define `var Thisit = $(this)` before `$.post()` and use `Thisit` instead of `$(this)` so your code should be something like

```
$(document).on('blur', '.part', function(){
    var ThisIt = $(this);
    var oldNumber = ThisIt.val().toUpperCase();
    $.post("part-interchange.php",{ part: ThisIt.val() } ,function(data) {
    //no data back then add class Red remove Green
        if (data=='no') {
                ThisIt.removeClass('shadeChange');
                ThisIt.removeClass('shadeGood');
                ThisIt.addClass('shadeBad');
        } else if (data=='yes') {
                ThisIt.removeClass('shadeChange');
                ThisIt.removeClass('shadeBad');
                ThisIt.addClass('shadeGood');
         } else if (data!='yes') {
                ThisIt.removeClass('shadeBad');
                ThisIt.removeClass('shadeGood');
                ThisIt.addClass('shadeChange');
                ThisIt.val(data);
           }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` in context is changed in ajax response: Improved your code a bit

```
$(document).on('blur', '.part', function(){
var oldNumber = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
var parent = $(this);
$.post("part-interchange.php",{ part:$(this).val() } ,function(data) {
//no data back then add class Red remove Green
    if (data=='no') {
            parent.removeClass('shadeChange');
            parent.removeClass('shadeGood');
            parent.addClass('shadeBad');
    } else if (data=='yes') {
    parent.removeClass('shadeChange');
            parent.removeClass('shadeBad');
            parent.addClass('shadeGood');
     } else if (data!='yes') {
            parent.removeClass('shadeBad');
            parent.removeClass('shadeGood');
            parent.addClass('shadeChange');
            parent.val(data);
       }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Becasue the this inside of the success of the Ajax call is in a different scope.A simple `console.log(this)` will show you that.

So what can you do? You can [bind the function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) inside or easier, define this outside and use it.

```
$(document).on('blur', '.part', function() {
  var part = $(this);
  var oldNumber = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
  $.post("part-interchange.php", {
    part: $(this).val()
  }, function(data) {
    //no data back then add class Red remove Green
    if (data == 'no') {
      part.removeClass('shadeChange removeClass').addClass('shadeBad');
    } else if (data == 'yes') {
      part.removeClass('shadeChange shadeBad').addClass('shadeGood');
    } else if (data != 'yes') {
      part.removeClass('shadeBad shadeGood').addClass('shadeChange').val(data);
    }
  });
});
```